# how to fail a jenkins job while parent jobs calls child job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a parent job which calls child job, the problem that i am facing as child job failing i am still getting success in parent job.

is there any thing which reports back to parent job and makes it fail.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the multijob plugin. This plugin will fail the job if downstream job fails.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin